# Visual Studio Auto Formatting not working on the aspx page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am running Visual Studio 2008.  I cannot get the auto format to work on the source code of my aspx page.  I have tried it from the edit menu and the ctrl K, D.  Nothing works.  If I manually fix everything, the next time I open the file the formatting is gone.  Here is a sample of what it looks like:

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="2" CssClass="ajax__myTab" Width="100%" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
    <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Work - Main" Enabled="true">
        <headertemplate>
            Main
        </headertemplate>
        <contenttemplate>
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        Escalated Inquiry ID:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPkey" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978049/fix-formatting-of-aspx-file-in-visual-studios). Also, make sure you don't have any missing closing tags.

Comment: I see the problem.  I am using AJAX and none of the tags are listed in the HTML editor.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this when there is a problem with the HTML.  If there is an error in syntax (missing a closing tag, for instance), then the parser doesn't know where the tabs should go.

**EDIT**

Based on your sample (assuming you pasted everything)

```
<cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="2" CssClass="ajax__myTab" Width="100%" ScrollBars="Horizontal">
    <cc1:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Work - Main" Enabled="true">
        <headertemplate>
            Main
        </headertemplate>
        <contenttemplate>
            <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        Escalated Inquiry ID:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPkey" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
```

, here is what is missing:

```
                </tr>
            </table>
        </contenttemplate>
    </cc1:TabPanel>
</cc1:TabContainer>
```

Comment: Any idea on how to find it. I just pasted the page into dreamweaver and it did not find a missing tag.

Comment: I just provided part of the page as an example of what the formatting looked like